# PostgreSQL database files

Tags: database, postgresql, binaryfiles, binary-data, wal

Let's consider we have a master database server with corresponding slave replica. Can we be confident about the database binary representations (and, maybe, WALs) are completely the same (byte-to-byte) on master and slave (maybe with some delay for data transaction).

Personally I think that the representations should be similar just according to methods of replications (e. g. WAL streaming), but I'd like to be sure about it.

Comment: Probably not. You could set up a leader and follower and check. Why do you need the database files (not the data) to be byte-for-byte the same?

Comment: Similar - always, identical - never. You can expect majority of data to be binary identical, but you can be sure some bits will differ in page and tuple headers, _fsm and _vm files, and many more places. If you create a local master/slave pair and run `diff -r --brief` to compare the clusters, you will see what I mean.

Comment: Ok, I've realized that. The main reason is a wish to have a single backup for master a slave to be able backup slave to it after some disaster